# How do I represent the following in flex and bison?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am using the following grammar to represent addition, multiplication of numbers

```
Stmts->epsilon|Stmt

E->Integer|Id|E*E|E+E

Integer -> digit+
```

Expression can reduce to Expression or Number or Number*Number or Number+Number

Integer can take one or more digits

Id can be a variable that needs to start with a lowercase letter followed by any number of lowercase letters or numbers

But, I also want to represent

```
Stmt -> Id = E | Id*=E | Id+=E |print E
```

The following is the grammar

```
stmt: 
| stmt expr_stmt

;

expr_stmt:
   expr TOK_SEMICOLON
   | TOK_PRINTLN expr TOK_SEMICOLON 
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "the value is %d\n", $2);
    }
|expr 
;



expr:
    expr TOK_ADD expr
   {
    $$ = $1 + $3;
   }
 | expr TOK_SUB expr
  {
    $$ = $1 - $3;
  }
 | expr TOK_MUL expr
  {
    $$ = $1 * $3;
  }
 | expr TOK_DIV expr
  {
 if($3 == 0) 
   yyerror("divide by zero");
 else
      $$ = $1 / $3; 
  }
 | TOK_NUM
  {     
    $$ = $1;
  }
| TOK_ID
| TOK_MUL TOK_EQ expr
| TOK_ADD TOK_EQ expr

;
```

It shows shift/reduce conflicts.

Comment: You need to make `+=` and friends single tokens from the lexer, rather than trying to build them in the parser.

Comment: You also need to add precedence declarations. The absence is what currently produces parsing conflicts

Comment: @user207421 Can you please elaborate

Comment: @rici I have added precedence for the following %left TOK_ADD TOK_SUB
%left TOK_MUL TOK_DIV

Comment: To clarify even further, you need the lexer to return say TOK_PLUSEQ on `+=` and so forth, rather than trying to parse TOk_PLUS TOK_EQ as a sequence in the grammar.